# ConstraintLayout margin_top doesn't work?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, margin, android-constraintlayout

i need to constrain my button constraint_top to myCardView constraint_bottom and set the margin_top of my button to 64dp. But for any reason its does not work.

That my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/shadow"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/myCardViewItem"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtItemValue"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_folder"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/item"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/myCardViewItemName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/myCardViewItem">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtItemNameValue"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_folder"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/item_name"
                android:inputType="text"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/myCardViewItemPrice"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myCardViewItemName">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtItemPriceValue"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_folder"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/item_price"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/myCardViewItemStoredQuantity"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myCardViewItemPrice">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtItemStoredQuantityValue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_folder"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/item_stored_quantity"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_shape"
    android:text="salvar"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myCardViewItemStoredQuantity" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewList"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Listar"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnRegister" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

That is the result of margin_top 64dp, or any value inputed. Dosen't works.

[image: Layout result]

I think this may have been caused by layout inheritance hierarchy, but i cant find the error. any one? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove from your button

> android:layout_margin="16dp"

And android:layout_marginTop="64dp" in your button will work
[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvVr3.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using

```
android:layout_margin="16dp"
```

and

```
android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
```

when you use layout_margin it set all margins including top, right, left and button to that number. So, if you use `android:layout_margin="16dp"` , it also sets `android:layout_marginTop="16dp"`.
So you should delete `android:layout_margin="16dp"` and it will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you can't build you application, try delete `+` in front of id in button declaration.  The plus sign is use for id declaration only.

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/myCardViewItemStoredQuantity"
```